# Test methods are not running

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, mstest

I added a test project in visual studio 2013.
I tried to run the a test method 
It gives below output.There was a **test method ,it did not run**.

NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering test is finished

Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:02.2029992) [image]

What should i do to resolve the error and run the test method?

Comment: You need to figure out why the DataAccessTest.dll isn't being loaded. Try using the Assembly Bind Viewer Log (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.100).aspx) to see if you can figure out why.

Comment: Can you show the test class?